# What protocols did the ARPANET use?

Tags: internet, history, network-protocols

The ARPANET is often mentioned as the Internet's precursor.  But what protocols did it run with if not TCP/IP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Control_Program

NCP was used in ARPANET before TCP/IP

It was fully replaced with TCP/IP in 1983, replacement started in 1981, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc801

Comment: That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

One of the greatest treasures produced by DARPA is probably the collection of early RFCs IENs and other *public* documents that record the development of the Internet. Try getting equivalent free documentation for ISO OSI or for proprietary technologies like Netware IPX/SPX. In part this is one important reason why Internet Protocols prevailed over the competition. The early RFCs were mostly concise, clear and easy to read and understand (this isn't so much true of later RFCs).

See [RFC1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1)

```
   Information is transmitted from HOST to HOST in bundles called
   messages.  A message is any stream of not more than 8080 bits,
   together with its header.  The header is 16 bits and contains the
   following information:

           Destination     5 bits
           Link            8 bits
           Trace           1 bit
           Spare           2 bits
```

Comment: The protocol went through *many* changes since RFC 1. One would need to read at least the first 1k RFCs (up until the NCP→TCP migration) to see how it looked at the end.

Comment: @grawity: Yes, the IENs are also interesting. For example IEN2 "We are screwing up in our design of internet protocols by violating the
principle of layering. Specifically we are trying to use TCP to do two
things: serve as a host level end to end protocol, and to serve as an internet packaging and routing protocol. These two things should be
provided in a layered and modular way. I suggest that a new distinct
internetwork protocol is needed"

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  I've looked into the early RFCs but could not identify a name for the protocols described therein (other than IMP software).